# Two question on ternary Cantor set & Jordan content

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, boolean-algebra, cantor-set

> Is it true that all subsets of the Cantor set have [Jordan content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure) zero?

What is the definition of countably generated Boolean algebra?

> Does the Boolean algebra of subsets $[0,1]$ which possess Jordan content is countably generated?

Sorry I updated the question.

Comment: *Positive* Jordan content? No.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I have updated the question. Exactly, since the Cantor set itself has zero content, so all subsets of it should have content $\leq 0$

Comment: The update doesn't really answer @Mark's question. When you say "have Jordan content", do you mean that the set has _positive_ Jordan measure, or merely that it is Jordan measurable?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Jordan measurable (even zero)

Answer (score 3):

The middle-thirds Cantor set has Jordan measure zero -- it is the intersection of a sequence of finite unions of intervals whose total length converge to zero.

Therefore every subset of it *also* has Jordan measure zero, since you can find a simple superset of it with arbitrary small content.

---

If the Boolean algebra of Jordan measurable sets were countably generated, it would itself be countable because then by definition every set in the algebra is generated from some finite sequence of joins, meets and complements from the generator elements. And these sequences of operations can be coded as integers using routine constructions.

However, every interval $[0,\alpha]$ is Jordan measurable, and there are uncountably many such intervals (namely one for each $\alpha\in [0,1]$). Therefore the algebra cannot be countably generated.

Comment: Very good answer, but I still I want you to explain "what is the definition of countably generated". Correct me if I am wrong. If $B$ is countably generated by a set, say $X$ (should this $X$ be countable), then each element $b$ in  $B$ is countable union of elements of $X$.

Comment: @Dilzan: The usual definitions of "countably generated" would be that the algebra $B$ has a countable subset $X$ which is contained in no proper subalgebra of $B$. Speaking about countable unions is certainly wrong, because such a thing doesn't even necessarily _exist_ when we talk about Boolean algebras.

Comment: I got it ... appreciate your help.